# MDX Sum values of lower level

Tags: mdx, olap

I am new to OLAP, I just designed my first cube and now I am trying to make some simple analyses. I have a simple time dimension that looks like this:

```
- Year
  - Month
    - DayOfWeek
```

Now I would like to sum all measures for e. g. Monday. I don't want to know the measure for Monday for every month of every year seperated (I am able to do this) but for all Mondays ever. Just one value.

Is it possible and if, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Time to break out the AdventureWorks sample and look at their time dimension. You need more attributes on your dimension. There should be attributes for Year, Month and Date that are arranged in a hierarchy, but the attribute for DayofWeek, MonthofYear, etc, should be separate if you need to aggregate on them.